# After update from local to server : Class 'category' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

EDIT: Changed lowercase 'c' to uppercase 'C' in belongsTo.... Only my carelessness...

On local machine is everything OK, error is AFTER upload to server.

I have basic One To One Relationship:

Symbol.php - model:

```
class Symbol extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'symbols';
    protected $softDelete = true;  

  public function category()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('category', 'id_category');
  }   
}
```

Category.php - model

```
class Category extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'categories';
}
```

I call this relationship like this:

```
$symbol = Symbol::find($id);
```

But if I want access to data:

```
$symbol->category->name;
```

On my local machine is everything ok BUT after upload to server i get ERROR:

```
 Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
 Class 'category' not found 
 $instance = new $related; (line 527)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try with capital `C` in `belongsTo`

Comment: Thx man it WORKS! But why it works on local? Different server settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why it works on local? Different server settings?

If it worked on your local machine and not on the server then I think, most probably you definitely  have `windows` operating system installed on your local machine and on the server, there is `linux` driven system. So, on `windows` `Category` and `category` doesn't matter but on `linux`, it does,so if you have a class `Category` and you refer it as `category` then it doesn't exist at all because `linux` is case sensitive.

[Check this](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hosting-plan-comparison/what-is-the-difference-between-linux-and-windows-hosting) and look at `Case Sensitivity`.

Comment: after spending hours on trying to fix this, i recall the time when people had recommended to develop on a linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

a `composer update` from the terminal seems to solve some of my problems when I've changed classnames etc in Laravel 4, have you tried it?.